# How does webpack bundler resolves named import?

Tags: performance, webpack

I have a named import statement for function from other file.
like this

```
import { getTax } from "fileA"
```

fileA is having various exports function like this

```
export function A(){}
export function B= function(){}
export function getTax= function(){}
```

will webpack add A, B and getTax in the bundled code?
I am using webpack 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default webpack bundler don't handle removal of dead code. For removal of dead code you have to some minifier like `UglifyJSPlugin` which support dead code removal.

Webpack provided great analogy for this:

> You can imagine your application as a tree. The source code and
>   libraries you actually use represent the green, living leaves of the
>   tree. Dead code represents the brown, dead leaves of the tree that are
>   consumed by autumn. In order to get rid of the dead leaves, you have
>   to shake the tree, causing them to fall.

For reference read this :
1) [Tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)
2) [UglifyJSPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/)

So in your case all 3 function will be imported. You have shake the bundler for this.